# How to get context services mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

So I'm trying to make a connection between my React.js APP and I'm trying to verify if a user exists already in the mongodb Atlas database collection. At first place I have imported the mongodbClient like this using the `app.currentUser`

```
const mongodb = app.currentUser.mongoClient('mongodb-atlas')
const tmpUsers = mongodb.db('tracker').collection('tmpUsers')
```

the problem is that in the first web site connection no user is authenticated so I cannot get `mongodb` like I did in the code before I also found this

```
const plants = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("example").collection("plants");
const plant = await plants.findOne();
// Return e.g. { "_id": "5f87976b7b800b285345a8b6", ... }
// instead of { "_id": { "$oid": "5f87976b7b800b285345a8b6" } }
return JSON.stringify(plant);
```

But what is `context` where they used `context.services...` because they didn't provide where to import the service from.
So the question is.
**How do I import the mongodb-atlas service?**

Comment: Are you using Realm? https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/functions/context/

Comment: Yeah but how do I import it?